# Spivak Chapter 7 problem 4

Tags: calculus

If $n-k$ is even and $\geq 0$, find a polynomial function with degree $n$ that has exactly $k$ roots.
When trying to solve this equation, i came up with:
$(x^{n-k+1})(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(k-1))$
which is degree $n$ and has $k$ roots, $0,1,2,3...k-1$
However I think i only use the fact that $n-k \geq 0 $, but I do not use the $n-k$ is even. Is my solution correct? 
Spivak's solution is quite clever,
[image]
It gets what we want and uses all the information, but i don't know if you have to use all the information

Comment: I am not sure what your book means by "exactly $k$ (real?) roots."  If multiplicities are accounted for, then your example has $n$ real roots (with $0$ occuring $n-k+1$ times) while the book's answer has exactly $k$ real roots.

Comment: If the question means "$k$ distinct roots" your answer is correct.

If the question means "$k$ distinct roots, allowing for repetition" you should go with Spivak's answer instead (which is correct in both cases)

Comment: Well in the next problem, 4(b), it's clarified that  multiplicities are accounted, actually it's the first time the book presents this idea so it defines what multiplicities are, so i guess, since in the previous problem you dont "know" this fact, you shouldn't account for them.

Comment: if multiplicities are counted, your solution has $n$ roots.

Comment: @PacoAntonio Spivak assumes you have an excellent precalculus background. It’s not correct to assume that multiplicity shouldn’t be thought of if it hasn’t been mentioned before.